AG-Grid pivot mode doesn't save at the group level
I have a table with over 60 columns. We use pivot mode to help users organize and group similar fields. AG-grid seems to allow saving column positions and sizes for the first level but not for the grouped levels.
Does anybody know a trick to save the order for the grouped levels? AG-Grid Pivot mode not saving when moving groups to a different location. Thanks for your help! Jason
I've tried moving level 2 and level 3 groups to different positions and saving (persistence) the table. But when I refresh the browser my groups are back to their original places.
It works find at the first level. just not at level 2 and 3.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
